# string split using regex and get data on both side

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse  a string as below but not able to get expected output
In value pair there can be {} or [] or () and they may contain \n and = both

Please check key 4

> 3=dkjashd\n4={AAAAAA \n45=45\n AAAAAA  \n AAAAAA}\n5=112

here output has to be

> 3=dkjashd
>
> 4={AAAAAA \n45=45\n AAAAAA  \n AAAAAA}
>
> 5=112

As above key gives wrong result with **"\h*\R\s*(?=\d*=)"** and **\s+(?=\d{1,2}=)** both

```
        String req="1=A  \n2=B\n3={AAAAAA}\n4={AAAAAA \n45=45\n AAAAAA  \n AAAAAA} \n5=AAAAAA \n6=[10]\n7=[]\n8=[10,11]\n99=0";

        String []str=req.split("\\d{1,2}=");
        Arrays.stream(str).forEach(data-> System.out.println("Data :"+ data));
```

Result:

> Data : Data :A
>
> Data :B
>
> Data :{AAAAAA}
>
> Data :{AAAAAA
>   Data :45=45  AAAAAA    AAAAAA}
>
> Data :AAAAAA
>
> Data :[10]
>
> Data :[]
>
> Data :[10,11]
>
> Data :0

Expected :

> Data :1=A
>
> Data :2=B
>
> Data :3={AAAAAA}
>
> Data :4={AAAAAA 45=45  AAAAAA    AAAAAA}
>
> Data :5=AAAAAA
>
> Data :6=[10]
>
> Data :7=[]
>
> Data :8=[10,11]
>
> Data :99=0

Can anyone help over it.

Comment: You're splitting *on* the number meaning - it will not be in the result-set...

Comment: This isn't what `split` is for. Use a matcher.

Comment: I'd suggest splitting with `split("\\h*\\R\\s*(?=\\d+=)")`, it will be safer since it splits only when there is a line break enclosed with 0+ whitespace(s) followed with 1+ digits and a `=`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you  tell how your regex differ from split("\\s+(?=\\d{1,2}=)");   as I see result is same

Comment: @gladiator The results are the same because `\s` matches any whitespace. You seem to need to only split when there is a line break (enclosed with any whitespace) followed with 1+ digits and `=`. So, if you have `"1=A  \n2=B\n3={AA 45=45 AAAA}` [anubhava's regex will not do the best job](https://regex101.com/r/uXq0yo/1). And [here is my regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/uXq0yo/2).

Comment: Thanks for this scenarios ... you are right  .... 
If possible can you add it as answer so It can help other

Comment: Good, I will add now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this regex with a looahead:

```
String [] strarr = req.split(
   "\\h*\\n+\\h*(?=\\d{1,2}=(?![^{}]*})(?![^()]*\\))(?![^\\]\\[]*]))");
Arrays.stream(strarr).forEach(data-> System.out.println("Data : "+ data));
```

- Regex `\\h*\\n+\\h*(?=\\d{1,2}=(?![^{}]*}))` splits on 1+ new lines surrounded by 0+ horizontal whitespaces that must be followed by 1 or 2 digits and `=` symbol.
- Negative lookahead-1 `(?![^{}]*})` asserts that we don't look for `\d{1,2}=` inside `{...}` .
- Negative lookahead-2 `(?![^()]*\))` asserts that we don't look for `\d{1,2}=` inside `(...)` .
- Negative lookahead-3 `(?![^\[\]]*])` asserts that we don't look for `\d{1,2}=` inside `[...]` .

(this is assuming you don't have escaped brackets)

You may also use:

```
Arrays.stream(strarr).forEach(data-> System.out.println("Data : "+data.replace("\n", "")));
```

if you don't want newline in output.

**Output:**

```
Data : 1=A
Data : 2=B
Data : 3={AAAAAA}
Data : 4={AAAAAA  AAAAAA   AAAAAA}
Data : 5=AAAAAA
Data : 6=[10]
Data : 7=[]
Data : 8=[10,11]
Data : 99=0
```

Comment: It fails for 1=A \n2=B\n3={AA 45=45 AAAA} as said in comment by Wiktor

Comment: I think i need to update question as there are many scenarios which are creating issue .

Comment: yes please update the question to make it clear and then we can design answer based on that

Comment: can u help by adding [] and () as well with {}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159242/discussion-between-anubhava-and-gladiator).

Comment: Now its working as per our discussion thank buddy will see on another scenarios on monday

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern/matcher to extract the required parts:

```
String req="1=A  \n2=B\n3={AAAAAA}\n4={AAAAAA \n AAAAAA  \n AAAAAA} \n5=AAAAAA \n6=[10]\n7=[]\n8=[10,11]\n99=0";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+=.*?)\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(req);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Data :"+ matcher.group(1));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Data :1=A
Data :2=B
Data :3={AAAAAA}
Data :4={AAAAAA
Data :5=AAAAAA
Data :6=[10]
Data :7=[]
Data :8=[10,11]
```

Comment: There is issue with data :4   it ignores rest of lines
Expe:   Data : 4={AAAAAA  AAAAAA   AAAAAA} 
out :  Data :4={AAAAAA